# need jenkins file configuration to deploy application on Deployit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, deployit, xl-deploy

i was using maven Jenkins job to deploy application to Deployit. now i want manual Jenkins file to deploy using the pipeline job which refer to our jenkins created file. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/concept/jenkins-xl-deploy-plugin.html) contains an example on how to use a Jenkinsfile with XL Deploy (previously known as Deployit).